# An interface has two type parameters. Can I implement the interface with the two types being the same, such that they are then compatible?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, types

This is an existing interface:

```
public interface MyInterface<T, U> {
    public T foo(U u);
}
```

I want to implement this interface under the assumption that T and U are the same type. I thought maybe I could leave the type parameters in as they are, and then as long as I only ever instantiate this particular implementation with two of the same type, that it might work:

```
public class MyOuterClass<A> {

    public class MyClass<T, U> implements MyInterface<T, U> {

        @Override
        public T foo(U u) {
            return u; //error here
    }

    //even though in the only instantiation of MyClass, T and U are the same
    private MyClass<A, A> myInstance = new MyClass<A, A>();

}
```

But, perhaps unsurprisingly, this doesn't work, as types T and U are incompatible.

So then I thought maybe I could change MyClass to specify that its types would always be the same, by changing it to something like `MyClass<A, A> implements MyInterface<A, A>` or similar, but I get errors saying that T is already defined.

Is there a way to implement MyClass so that its two types will be the same?

(I'm more of a C++ guy than Java, so sorry if I'm missing something fundamental about Java's generic's here.)

Comment: You're using two different type parameters; the compiler can't figure out your intent, because if they were intended to be the same type, you would have said `MyClass<T, T>` instead of `MyClass<T, U>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your myclass needs to look like this:

```
public class MyClass<T> implements MyInterface<T, T> {

    @Override
    public T foo(T in) {
        return in;
    }
}
```

Let's review what your suggested class definition does:

```
public class MyClass<T, U> implements MyInterface<T, U>
```

In this code, `T` and `U` do *two things* each:

- in the first occurance they define a type variable of your `MyClass` class
- in the second occurance they specify the concrete type of the `MyInterface` class

Since inside the body of your class `T` and `U` are unbounded type variables (i.e. nothing is known about the actual types), they are assumed to be incompatible.

By having only a single type variable in your `MyClass` you make your assumption explicit: there's only a single type, and I'm using it for both types of the interface.

Last but not least: remember that the compilation of a type is **complete** once the source is fully handled. In other words: contrary to what C++ does, "instantiation" of a generic type ("template type" or similar in C++; Sorry for my rusty terminology) does **not** handle. `MyClass<Foo>` and `MyClass<Bar>` are the same type, as far as the JVM is concerned (only the compiler actually distinguishes them).

Answer (score 1):

Define a single type parameter for `MyClass`:

```
class MyOuterClass<A> {

    public class MyClass<T> implements MyInterface<T, T> {

        public T foo(T u) {
            return u;
        }
    }

    // Need only one 'A' here.
    private MyClass<A> myInstance = new MyClass<A>();

}
```

When you say

```
public class MyClass<T> implements MyInterface<T, T> {
```

... you are defining *one* generic variable for `MyClass` and you are saying that it fulfills both the roles `T` and `U` in `MyInterface`.